# What is the correct way to write multi-line code in JSDoc comment in a javascript/typescript project in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

When working on a javascript/typescript project in VSCode, I want to write multi-line code in comment. Knowing that VSCode supports markdown syntax in comment, I go ahead and write:

````
/**
* ```ts
* { deliverQuestionClicked: { [pageNum]: false } }
* ```
*/
deliverQuestionClicked: {},
````

However when I hover on that variable, VSCode renders the comment in a ugly looking way:

[image: vscode_1.png]

As the screenshot shown above, there're extra `*` that I don't want.

So I wonder what is the correct way to write multi-line code in comment?

### **Update 2020/9/25**

I can confirm this problem doesn't exist in VSCode 1.49.1

Code:

````
class TopRow extends React.Component {
    state = {
        /**
        * ```ts
        * { deliverQuestionClicked: { [pageNum]: false } }
        * ```
        */
        deliverQuestionClicked: {},
    };
}
````

When I hover over that class property, it shows the JSDoc perfectly:

[image: image.png]

Comment: @Pascalius are you using any plugins? I don't see similar behavior.

Comment: @DipenShah Yes, but which version of VSCode are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Must have been fixed.

In VSC 1.48 with this code

````
class TopRow {
  state = {
    /**
    * ```ts
    * { deliverQuestionClicked: { [pageNum]: false } }
    * ```
    */
    deliverQuestionClicked: {}
  }
}
````

I get

[image]

Comment: Yes, I can also confirm this in VSCode 1.49.1. Please see my update above.

Answer (score 3):

### In **[JSDoc-format](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/jsdoc-format/)**,

Basic format rules for *JSDoc comments*.

- Each line contains an asterisk and asterisks must be aligned
- Each asterisk must be followed by either a space or a newline (except for the first and the last)
- The only characters before the asterisk on each line must be whitespace characters
- One line comments must start with `/**` and end with `*/`
- Multiline comments don’t allow text after `/**` in the first line (with option `"check-multiline-start"`)

> You can optionally specify the option `"check-multiline-start"` to enforce the first line of a multiline JSDoc comment to be empty.

### [`TypeScript in Visual Studio Code`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript)

> To **[disable JSDoc comment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_jsdoc-support)** suggestions in TypeScript,
> set  `"typescript.suggest.completeJSDocs": false`.

**To add a comment**

- press `Ctrl+Alt+C` twice
- or select `'Comment code'` from your context menu
- or insert `/**` above the line of code.

More info [visit](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salbert.comment-ts)

Answer (score -2):

you can use JavaScript's multi-line comment that begins with /* and ends with */. You don't need extra *.

Answer (score -3):

Simply Use /* */ before and after the comment. For Example:

```
/*
This is a multi line comment
I can type on a different line
Without having to worry so far
I close my multi line commen with
an asterix and a backward slash
*/
```